# Where to configure jetty-web.xml in the standalone java application which uses Spring context?

Tags: java, spring, apache, jetty, load-balancing

So, I am starting up Jetty using the Spring Context, in a standalone java application.

The deployment environment however uses an Apache server for load balancing Web requests to different instances of this application.

Unfortunately, I don't know much about Apache Load Balancing, however things are made simpler for me, and all I have to do is define a '***worker name***' for the Jetty instance, probably in the Spring Context file; **can anyone help me do this ?**

I am shown the below configuration where I should probably be matching the '***jetty2***' worker name in my Jetty configuration found in the spring context xml file:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
   <Get name="sessionHandler">
     <Get name="sessionManager">
       <Call name="setIdManager">
         <Arg>
           <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionIdManager">
             <Set name="WorkerName">jetty2</Set>
           </New>
         </Arg>
       </Call>
     </Get>
   </Get>
</Configure>
```

Comment: Not sure  i understand your question, but have a look https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_mod_proxy#Configuring_mod_proxy_balancer

Comment: I have seen this page, basically I want to define the configuration above in my application, it belongs to file 'jetty-web.xml', which they say I should add to 'WEB-INF', however I don't have 'WEB-INF' in my application, so can anyone tell me where this configuration goes in the standalone java application.